# Defining getters and setters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting following error for the setter defined in the javascript: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

The code4 is as follows:

setter defn :

```
this.__defineSetter('_myList', function(list)  
        {
              log.debug("in setter ....");  
             if(this._myList == list)  
            {  
                 log.debug("in setter..");    
                 return;           

            }  
            this._myList = list;  
         });
```

call:

```
myMethod = function(msg)    
{  
  try  
    {       
     this.myList = msg.myList;  
    }catch(e)
    {
        log.debug("error in calling setter... " + e);
    }  
}
```

I am unable to figure out why is it going to infinite loop??

Comment: Doesn't call the last statement in the setter function the same function again?

Comment: yeah you have to store the value else where, this is a bad pattern and use of `__defineSetter()` has been deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/DefineSetter  i would avoid these APIs if i were you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call the setter from within the setter...

```
this._myList = list;
```

Should create another 'private' variable to store the value. Something like this...

```
var _myInnerList;

this.__defineSetter__('_myList', function(list) {
  log.debug("in setter ....");  
  if(_myInnerList === list) {  
    log.debug("in setter..");    
    return;           
  }  
  _myInnerList = list;  
});
```

Also use === for comparisons (always) and change [__defineSetter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/DefineSetter) into...

```
__defineSetter__
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
this._myList = list;
```

it invokes the defined setter, which causes the infinite recursion.