# Angular 2: How to watch for changes in a data object (not a component)?

Tags: angular, typescript

The Angular 2 documentation talks about LifeCycle hooks like the ngOnChanges hook, which will let you watch for changes in a Component:

[LifeCycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

The Plunkr example that demonstrates how to use OnChanges specifically indicates that changes to properties of data objects referenced by the Component that implements OnChanges will not trigger a call to OnChanges:

[Plunkr Example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/lifecycle-hooks/ts/plnkr.html)

Here's a snippet of the Component in that example that implements OnChanges:

```
export class MyHeroComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() hero: Hero;
  @Input() power: string;
```

If you change hero.name, OnChanges won't be called.  If you change power, it will be called.

So what is the recommended solution if you want to watch for changes to any property of an object like hero?  It sounds like you could do something with $scope.$watch in AngularJS 1.x, although I'm not sure if that is for watching individual properties or if you can watch an entire object.  But it looks like that probably isn't an option in Angular 2.0, with no $scope variable available.

My goal here is to run code when any value in my data model changes.  This is for writing a generic framework that is used to display custom data entry screens with custom data objects, where the data entry screen can provide its own validation script, a script to indicate which screen to go to next, etc.  I want to call certain scripts when any property of the underlying data object changes, which means I can't put any sort of "watches" on every property of the data (since the generic framework won't know what those properties are).

Note that I am new to both AngularJS 1.x and Angular 2.0, and I'm trying to wrap my head around them.  I gather there is a concept called Observable that may apply here, but I'm not entirely sure yet whether that has to do with incrementally retrieving results from (e.g.) a data service, or watching for changes to an object.  My apologies if I'm overlooking something obvious or not expressing myself clearly.  My background is .NET, so I'm trying to map my skillset there onto Angular concepts.

Comment: I've reproduced this, it seems to be a bug in angular2. I do not see any issues currently open about this on github. Maybe you should make one. :)

Comment: I made a smaller example here http://plnkr.co/edit/BEPEILzYtlOxLq7oTJl1?p=preview

Comment: Are you sure it is a bug? The UI for the sample specifically indicates that changes to hero.name won't trigger a change, which implies to me that it is a design decision rather than a bug. Ie, deep changes to referenced objects aren't intended to be watched by default for performance reasons.

Comment: This does seem intentional. Still the documentation does not actually say anything about objects not being received, only that it happens when the input changes. The documentation could be improved at least. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining getters and setters in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357331/defining-getters-and-setters-in-javascript)